# swift json parsing based on parameter

Tags: json, web-services, swift3

I am having the following web service response in which I need parse the parameters based on "MainServiceCategories_ID"
Here is the response

```
{
"Entity": {
    "ID": 20021,
    "UserTypeID": 1,
    "UserType": null,
    "UserID": 30046,
    "Code": "lPx1lTEq",
    "Name": "بدراء",
    "EnglishName": "Badra",
    "IconProfileImageID": "",
    "MainImageProfileImageID": "EED372C3-5C4F-E711-8100-0CC47A343427",
    "LocationLng": 78.37021,
    "LocationLat": 17.432563,
    "Services": [
        {
            "ID": 11788,
            "MainServiceCategories_ID": 3,
            "ServiceCategories_ID": 6,
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Parent_ID": 6,
                    "Name": “John”,
                    "EnglishName": “Johnny”,

                },
                {
                    "Parent_ID": 6,
                    "Name": “Ronny”,
                    "EnglishName": “Ronny”,

                }]
        },
         {
            "ID": 11788,
            "MainServiceCategories_ID": 2,
            "ServiceCategories_ID": 6,
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Parent_ID": 6,
                    "Name": “Samuel”,
                    "EnglishName": “Samuel”,
                },
                {
                    "Parent_ID": 6,
                    "Name": “Badri”,
                    "EnglishName": “Badri”,
                }]
        },
       {
            "ID": 11788,
            "MainServiceCategories_ID": 3,
            "ServiceCategories_ID": 6,
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Parent_ID": 6,
                    "Name": “emma”,
                    "EnglishName": “Emma”,
                },
                {

                    "Parent_ID": 6,
                    "Name": “Sean”,
                    "EnglishName": “Sean”,
                }]
        }]
```

this is the code I am writing to do it

```
do{
    let entityDic = responseDictionary["Entity"] as? [String: Any]
    let servicesDic = entityDic?["Services"] as? [Any]

    for i in 0 ..< servicesDic!.count {

        let services = servicesDic?[i] as? [String: Any]
        let availableServices = services!["EnglishName"]

        servicesNamesArr.append(availableServices! as! String)

        let children = services!["Children"]
        childrenServices.append(children!)

        let MainServiceCategories_ID = services!["MainServiceCategories_ID"]
        MainServiceCategoriesID.append(MainServiceCategories_ID!)
    }
    print("childrenServices \(childrenServices)")
}

catch let error{
    print(error)
}
```

I am able to get upto children dictionaries. Now the thing is I am trying to parse "English name" under children section and separate them based on "MainServiceCategories_ID" where I am getting fatal error in unwrapping the value.
for example if MainServiceCategories_ID =1  then that "English Name" need to be store in an array and if MainServiceCategories_ID =2 then into another array

Comment: Don't use force unwrapping when parsing `JSON` responses from web services. The `JSON` response might be flawed or just change over time and if you use force unwrapping, your app will definitely crash at some point. Use safe optional unwrapping. Also please follow the `Swift` naming convention by starting all variable names with lowercase chars

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to parse *"EnglishName"* as a key of an element of the *"Services"* array and not as a key of a *"Children"* element. *"Services"* does not have a key *"EnglishName"*, so you can't store that in `servicesNamesArr`. `servicesDic` should also be an Array of Dictionaries and not an array of `Any` objects.

See below code using guard statements using safe optional unwrapping:

```
do{
    guard let entityDic = responseDictionary["Entity"] as? [String: Any] else {return}
    guard let servicesDic = entityDic?["Services"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}

    for service in services {
        guard let MainServiceCategoryID = service["MainServiceCategories_ID"] as? Int else {return}
        MainServiceCategoriesID.append(MainServiceCategoryID)

        guard let children = service["Children"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}
        childrenServices.append(children)

        if MainServiceCategoryID == 3 {
            for child in children {
                if let availableService = child["EnglishName"] as? String {
                    servicesNamesArr.append(availableService)
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    print("childrenServices \(childrenServices)")
} catch let error{
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I already parsed "MainServiceCategories_ID" and "Children" successfully. I need to parse "English Name" under children section when MainServiceCategories_ID = 3

Comment: So you actually want to store the ""EnglishName" property of the children in `servicesNamesArr`?

Comment: @stackqstns check my updated answer and tell me if this is what you need

Comment: I am getting an error says " Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String" at this point "        if MainServiceCategoryID == 3, let availableService = children["EnglishName"] as? String {
"

Comment: Forgot `children` is an array, updated my answer to iterate through the children array, please check it

Comment: Awesome !! David Pasztor you are a gem man . You saved me , thnq

Comment: Glad I could help. If you sound my answer helpful, please accept it as an answer.